# Nodejs: collection.forEach(console.log) is behaving differently than collection.forEach(function(x) {console.log(x)}) why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

Specifically, this  code:

```
fs = require('fs')
path = require('path')
var filePath = process.argv[2]
var ext = "." + process.argv[3]
fs.readdir(filePath, function(err, files) {
  var results = files.filter(function(file) { return path.extname(file) === ext })
  results.forEach(function(result) { console.log(result) })
})
```

outputs:

```
CHANGELOG.md

LICENCE.md

README.md
```

vs this code:

```
fs = require('fs')
path = require('path')
var filePath = process.argv[2]
var ext = "." + process.argv[3]
fs.readdir(filePath, function(err, files) {
  var results = files.filter(function(file) { return path.extname(file) === ext })
  results.forEach(console.log)
})
```

outputs:

```
CHANGELOG.md 0 [ 'CHANGELOG.md', 'LICENCE.md', 'README.md' ] 

LICENCE.md 1 [ 'CHANGELOG.md', 'LICENCE.md', 'README.md' ]

README.md 2 [ 'CHANGELOG.md', 'LICENCE.md', 'README.md' ]
```

It's my understanding that both styles of calling forEach should print the same result in this case. Why the difference in behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) passes *more than one argument*. Most of them time, people just use the first, which is the individual element, but the others are there.

So `results.forEach(console.log)` is like

```
results.forEach(function(element, index, elements) {
    console.log(element, index, elements);
});
```

And (in NodeJS) `console.log` takes *a variable number of arguments*. It prints the arguments it gets separated by spaces.

So you get the element, the index, and all the elements on each line.

---

FYI, writing `results.forEach(console.log)` is unusual for another reason. It causes `.log` to be called with the *global context.* In the case of Node, it works fine, but if you try `[1,2,3].forEach(console.log)` in Chrome, you'll get "TypeError: Illegal invocation". 'Course that doesn't mean you can't do it; just that it will look odd to a lot of JS programmers.

Answer (score 2):

[`array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) passes multiple arguments to the callback you pass in: the current value, the index of the current value in `array`, and `array` itself. `console.log` accepts any number of arguments and prints each one on the same line, each argument separated by a space.